# Python programming, getting the same value over and over instead of it increasing

Tags: python

So I am working on assignment for college and am still very new to coding so here is the question. At one college, the tuition for a full-time student is $8,000 per semester. It has been announced that the tuition will increase by 3 percent each year for the next five years. Write a program with a loop that `displays the projected semester tuition amount for the next five years.

```
tuition_increase = 0.03
tuition = 8000
tuition_total = 0
years = 5

print('tuition_total\tyears')
print('--------------------')
for years in range (1, years + 1)
    tuition_total = (tuition * tuition_increase) + tuition
    print(tuition_total, '/t', years)
```

I keep getting the same value over and over instead of it increasing by the tuition increase for each year

Comment: I see there is syntax error in for loop. Are you sure it is printing some output or just syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't sum `tuition_total` value to `tuition_total` value calculated from the previous step try it on following way.

```
tuition_total = ((tuition * tuition_increase) + tuition) + tuition_total
```

or

```
tuition_total += (tuition * tuition_increase) + tuition
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `tuition_total` just assign back to `tuition`, e.g.:

```
In []:
tuition_increase = 0.03
tuition = 8000
years = 5

print('tuition\tyears')
print('--------------------')
print(tuition, '\t', 0)

for years in range (1, years + 1):
    tuition *= (1+tuition_increase)
    print(tuition, '\t', years)

Out[]:
tuition years
--------------------
8000     0
8240.0   1
8487.2   2
8741.816     3
9004.07048   4
9274.1925944     5
```

As you can see you will need to fix your formatting.

You can also use `itertools.accumulate()` to do these things:

```
In []:
tuition_increase = 0.03
tuition = 8000
years = 5
print('{:10}{}'.format('tuition', 'years'))
print('-'*20)
for year, tuition in enumerate(it.accumulate(it.repeat(tuition, years+1), lambda x, y: x*(1+tuition_increase))):
    print('{:<10.2f}{}'.format(tuition, year))

Out[]:
tuition   years     
--------------------
8000.00   0         
8240.00   1         
8487.20   2         
8741.82   3         
9004.07   4         
9274.19   5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's corrected one. First line after `for` is the correct formula for calculating compound interest. Note, that I start indexing years for it from zero.

`print()` changed to use `.format()` in order to get tabulated output.

```
tuition_increase = 0.03
tuition = 8000
tuition_total = 0
years = 5

print('tuition_total\tyears')
print('--------------------')
for years in range (0, years ):
    tuition_total = tuition * (1+tuition_increase)** years
    print('{0:<15} {1}'.format(int(tuition_total), years+1))
```

will print

```
tuition_total   years
--------------------
8000            1
8240            2
8487            3
8741            4
9004            5
```

Comment: Please explain what changes you've made and why. Otherwise this is essentially a code-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

Small change need to be done.

```
tuition_increase = 0.03
tuition = 8000
tuition_total = 0
years = 5

print('tuition_total\tyears')
print('--------------------')
for years in range (1, years + 1):
    tuition = (tuition * tuition_increase) + tuition
    print(tuition, '/t', years)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the suggested solution from Tony Gaddis' book, Starting out with Python (Pearson Revel):

```
    tuition = 8000
    for i in range(1, 6):
        tuition *= 1.03
        if i == 1:
            print("In 1 year, the tuition will be $" + str(tuition) + ".")
        else:
            print("In "+str(i)+" years, the tuition will be $" + str(tuition) + ".")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it and got it right.

```
tuition = 8240.00
tuition1 = 8000
rate = 0.03

for year1 in range(1, 2):
    tuition1 = tuition1 * (1 + rate)
    print(f"In {year1} year, the tuition will be ${tuition1:.2f}.")
    for year in range (2, 6):
        tuition *= (1 + rate)
        print(f"In {year} years, the tuition will be ${tuition:.2f}.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing my code assuming that the college has 3 semesters in a year, which is typical.

```
tuition = 8000 * 3
for x in range(1, 6):
    tuition *= 1.03
    if x == 1:
        print("In 1 year, the tuition will be $" + str((" %.2f" %tuition) + "."))
    else:
        print("In "+str(x)+" years, the tuition will be $" + str((" %.2f" %tuition) + "."))
```

Answer (score 0):

After I got the answer wrong, the below answer popped up as correct. I've notice the answers always seem to be much simpler than what I put.

```
tuition = 8000.0

for i in range(1, 6):
    tuition *= 1.03
    if i == 1:
    print(f'In 1 year, the tuition will be ${tuition}.')
    else:
        print(f'In {i} years, the tuition will be ${tuition}.')
```